# need help with ADO in VB6

Tags: vb6, ado

I am making a POS system for a friend of mine, real small and simple.

Pretty much everything is coded right now except and inventory view

I am trying to make it so when it clicks a button it will load up into a listview
the UPC codes and the name associated with that UPC.

I am new to programming and I am trying to do this myself. I know I need to get a number of items in the database (how many UPC's) and then do a loop adding info in a listview.

but I am having trouble getting how many lines are in the database to start and end a loop

Comment: A good deal depends on whether you are using DAO or ADO objects for database access.  Telling us this will probably produce a more targeted answer for you.  In general though Recordsets have a RecordCount property that can be used depending on the CursorType you have requested.  You can also do Count(*) queries to get record counts.

Comment: Sorry, I see the title says ADO in it.

Answer (score 1):

This would be easier if you posted some of your code, so we could see what you are starting with.

However, you should be able to do something like THIS (My VB/ADO is rusty, so I might blow the syntax a little. As Chris notes above, VB6 is getting a little long in the tooth . . .). In most cases, you should not need to know how many records are returned in order to populate your listView - Just use a "Do Until " Loop As follows:

```
Public Sub LoadListview()
    Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

    Dim SQL As String
    SQL = _
        "SELECT . . . " & _
        "FROM . . . " & _
        "WHERE . . . "

    Set cn = New ADODB.Connection

    With cn
        .Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
        .ConnectionString = "YourConnectionString"
        .Open
    End With

    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

    rs.Open SQL, cn, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly

    With rs
        If Not .EOF Then
            Do Until .EOF
                ' Your code to populate your ListView Here
            .MoveNext
            Loop
        End If
    End With

    rs.Close
    cn.Close

        Set rs = Nothing
    Set cn = Nothing

End Sub
```

Note that I have simplified things here a little. in reality, if you are passing criteria into the WHERE clause, you should generally use PARAMETERS in conjunction with an ADODB.Command Object. I did not include an ADODB.Command in this example.

Comment: Here is an example of how im coding it, your code is very complex for me to understand

Comment: `Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
rs.Open "tblitem", con, adOpenDynamic, adLockPessimistic
rs.MoveLast
x = rs.Fields("itemcode") + 1
Text1.Text = x`

this is me just trying to get the number of lines in the database

Comment: @enko: Hmm, this is not complex. If you don't understand this, you're going to be completely lost when trying to write the rest of the application in VB 6. I suggest picking up a book that teaches you how to program in the language. And, as others have suggested, if you have no prior experience with VB 6, you might be best off starting with a different, more modern language. VB.NET or C# are good choices for database interaction.

Comment: @XIVSolutions: In scanning this code for complexity, I noticed that you apparently feel the need to declare all variables at the top of the method. Why, exactly? Is that just an old habit from years of working in languages that *did* require that? There are many advantages to declaring variables *just* above the line of code(s) where they're needed. It doesn't make a *huge* deal in this snippet, but it's certainly something to consider for more complicated code.

Comment: @Cody this is the last thing of my program im trying to do. I do want to start in VB.Net but the little that I do know is in vb6. once I am finished with this part i will be moving onto vb.net

Comment: @CodyGray - I went and copies this out of an old VBA Project I had on my laptop. You are correct - anymore, I declare variables when and where needed. It's been too long for me to try typing this out manually in my post. I probably would have gotten something wrong!

Comment: @Enko -In your code, you can use the rs.RecordCount function. However, unless you initialize your recordset with the adOpenStatic keyword, the funtion will return -1. I seriously recommend using code such as I have posted above if you need to populate a Listview.

Comment: @CodyGray - NOT to say I don't have some old habits from the vba/vb6 days which still plague me . . . ;-)

Comment: @Enko: The advantage of @XIVSolutions' option is that you dont' need to know the record count.  The while loop will just iterate through each item in the collection until it reaches the .EOF or end of the collection (stands for end of file).

Comment: @XIVSolutions:  If you want to use rs.RecordCount and get the actual result rather than -1 all you have to do is call rs.MoveLast right before it and it will the correctly populate the RecordCount property.  It's a hacky workaround, but it works :-)

Comment: @ Cody: Actually there are 2 schools of thought of where to place declarations and placing them at the top has nothing to do with "old habits". Some find management of declarations easier when they are all in one place. I have seen this discussed before and it was resolved as personal preference and not right or wrong. There is no point in trying to bring other platform coding styles when discussing VB6.